# Getting color code in image

Tags: colors, paint, color-codes

How to get a color code of a particular region in an image using a tool or paint
Can you suggest some

Comment: I can suggest that you try something yourself.

Comment: IMO this is not a question related to software developing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this if you're running Windows : http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php